# Today I have been

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect-progressive

A women who has just had an operation is surprised and happy she isn't in any pain.

She says: "I thought for sure I'd be in a lot more pain and would find it difficult doing things but today I have been washing dishes, folding some clothes, playing with my little 3yo on the floor ".

Is she talking about the nature of her activities or is she talking about repeated activities? I think she is talking about the nature of her activities. What do you think?

Comment: You're right. There's no reason to suppose she did ***any*** of those three activities on more than one separate occasion (i.e. - there's no reason to suppose "repeated" is a relevant implication of the verb form here). But that doesn't mean she ***didn't*** do some or all of those things repeatedly - just that the particular words she used convey nothing at all about that.

Comment: ...she could just as well have said *today I washed dishes, folded some clothes, and played with my little 3yo on the floor*. Optionally with ***have*** before ***washed*** - none of these changes make any *specific* difference to the meaning. They're just different alternative stylistic choices, that don't affect meaning in a way that would be universally recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite get what you meant by "the nature of her activities", but the woman is describing her day which hasn't finished yet. She is being interviewed on the same day the mentioned activities took place.

She could have used Present Perfect (or even Past Simple - as pointed out by @FumbleFingers in the comments), which would have been equally acceptable.

> Today I have washed dishes, folded some clothes, played with my little 3yo on the floor.

However, by using Present Perfect Continuous she stresses the duration of each activity. She had quite a busy day, she was physically active and she didn't feel any discomfort or pain throughout the day.

Comment: Just out of interest, where did you learn English? You are really good and I want to know  how you achieved this fluency.

Comment: @anouk I am far from being fluent, I am still learning... I think some self-study books (I love [these series from Cambridge](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation?webSubjects[]=Grammar%2C+Vocabulary+and+Pronunciation&lvar[]=British+English&sortOrder=family_pubDate%5Bdesc%5D&layout=undefined&tab=undefined&page=1&openOptions[]=facet_webSubjects&openOptions[]=facet_lvar&openOptions[]=facet_format&openOptions[]=facet_cef)) and immersion in the language help

Comment: I have been having problems with the different nuances, and I mean nuances, not the obvious differences, in the usage of present perfect simple and continuous. Any suggestions?

Comment: @anouk generally, the former is about result/state, whereas the latter emphasises progress/process and I think all small details are derived from these main concepts... And don't overcomplicate the matter, don't let this tense prevent you from exploring the language's beauty further :)

Comment: How do you immerse in a language when you live in a country where that language is not spoken?

Comment: @anouk pretend you are a foreigner and speak English :) In my experience, people in the Netherlands are very friendly, have [a great command of English](https://www.ef.com/wwen/epi/) and can instantly switch to it when needed